# Holonomic splitting

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

I am reading the book "Introduction to the h-Principle" by Eliashberg and Mishachev. At the moment I try to understand the Section 1.7 Holonomic splitting on page 12 but without success. I do not understand the Holonomic splitting proposition. What does it exactly say? Can one put this in mathematical language? I think it means that over some sufficiently small ball $U\subset V$ one can write the bundle $X^{(r)}\rightarrow V$ as the trivial fibration $U\times \mathbb{R}^{qN_{r}} \rightarrow U$. What I do not understand is why one needs a holonomic section for that?  Hope there is somebody who can explain those things to me.

cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem says that there does not only exist a trivialisation, but even a holonomic trivialisation. In the end, the holonomic sections are the ones that carry geometric meaning, so they are the ones you are interested in. The theorem says that once you have one holonomic section, you get a lot of them (via the holonomic trivialisation). The holonomic splitting theorem is needed in the proof of Thom Transversality (Theorem 2.3.2).

Comment: I do not understand how such a trivialisation looks like. Does it mean that if one picks a ball $U \subset V$ then one looks at the submanifold $F(U)\subset X^{(r)}$ and this submanifold has a tubular neighbourhood $\nu \subset X^{(r)}$ which at the same time is a fibration $\nu \rightarrow U$ such that $\nu$ is diffeomorphic to $J^{r}(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{q})$? I am a bit confused since by the term "section" the authors mean both the section as a map and its image.

Comment: Is it correct what I have said above? If yes how can one prove such a thing?

Comment: For the first two lines of your comment: Yes. The think the fibration property should be part of the definition of "tubular neighbourhood"?

Comment: I am not sure about whether $\nu$ is diffeomorphic to $J^r( \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^q)$. At least, that is not the point. The point is that the horizontal sections from $\nu$ are holonomic. I understand though that you are confused by the use of the term "section". Still, I think it makes no difference which point of view you take.

Comment: What do you mean by horizontal sections from $\nu$?

Comment: OK, it *is* confusing. You have sections of the original fibration $p: X \rightarrow V$, sections of the jet bundle and holonomic sections of the jet bundle, corresponding to sections of $p$ that satisfy the PDR. These are the ones we care about. By the holonomic splitting theorem, we know that once there is one local holonomic section, then you can "shift" this section parallelly inside a tubular neighbourhood and the parallel shifts will again be holonomic. But maybe I still didn't really understand your question.

Comment: By "horizontal sections from $\nu$" I mean sections "parallel" to the one we started with as defined on the top of page 13.

Comment: You mean page 12 ? page 13 is the next chapter :). What exactly do you mean by "parallel" ?

Comment: In the book I use (AMS, printed 2002), the section "Holonomic splitting" starts at the bottom of page 12 and ends at the top of page 14. But never mind, in my version of the book, the holonomic trivialisation is defined right above the theorem.

Comment: Yes I see, I guess I have some other version :)